# How to move custom object from winter'16 sandbox to summer'15 sandbox?

Tags: apex, visualforce, rest-api, api

I wanna move my custom object from my upgraded sandbox (winter'16 ) to my lower version sandbox ( summer'15 ) ?
Is there any way to move custom object ?

Comment: If you are getting an error, I've read that breaking your deployment down to smaller changes sets has worked for others in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be any problem using a change set. As long as the first target you deploy to is a summer '15 sandbox. That will then set the 'version' of the change set.

If you have already deployed to a summer '15 sandbox and thus get an error, create another clone of the change set and do the deployment to the winter '16 instance. That will work fine and will contain the same data (except if there are winter '16 specific contents, those obviously will not deploy to a summer '15 instance).

Comment: compatibility issue is comming...  we can move trigger, class , vf pages to lower version and move but how to do entire object ?

Comment: you mean object, fields, page layouts, validation etc? You can all add them to the change set (also the object). A nice trick to get all fields for an object in 1 view is to only add the page layout, then click 'View/add dependencies' and it will show you all you need to get that page layout to deploy (object and fields).